# How to show a legend in QwtPlot3D?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, legend

I am working with QwtPlot3D now and I need to show a legend, i.e. something like this:

[image]

But I don't know how, and I can't find a suitable tutorial, or examples on the internet. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/web/doxygen/classQwt3D_1_1Plot3D-members.html

In its list of all members for Plot3D, it lists:

`void showColorLegend (bool show)`

It that doesn't work, you probably will need to create an instance of `ColorLegend` and make sure it has the elements you want it to show.

http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/web/doxygen/classQwt3D_1_1ColorLegend.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. Any more suggestions?